# how to specify point of sale dashboard for a user in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale

How i can specify point of sale dashboard for specific user/ users who can see his/ her orders on dashboard when they logged into point of sale via their login account ?

Is there possibility to write expression with multiple OR / And conditions ?

Comment: You should see the POS settings in the user configs. From there you can assign the POS to the user.

Comment: Let me explain, i want every logged in user only view his/ her point of sale dashboard instead to view all dashboards.

Comment: You need to create record rule for that.
See this video of youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRHer19bBRA

Comment: I got your point, but point of sale is quit different by models attributes where some attribute contains same value. e.g company_id  is 1 in every model

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, this is how to Restrict POS user from viewing other users' orders

Create a new **Record Rule** (Settings > Security > Record Rules)

Named it anything you want

Object is *Point of Sales Orders*

Rule Definition: `[('user_id','=',user.id)]`

Groups *Point of Sale / User*

Now your POS users should only see orders created by themself.

---

You can also Assign a specific User to opening session on one POS by

1. **Create a field** (Settings > Database Structure > Fields)

   Named it: `x_user_id`

   Field type: `many2one`

   Model: `pos.config`

   Relation of object: `res.users`
2. Add the field to **pos.config.form.view** (Settings > User Interface > Views)

   `<group name="assigned_users" string="Assigned Users">
       <field name="x_user_id" string="Assigned Users" />
   </group>`
3. Create a **Record Rule** (Settings > Security > Record Rules)

   Named it anything you want

   Object: `pos.config`

   Rule Definition: `[('x_user_id','=',user.id)]`

   Groups: `Point of Sale / User`
4. **Assign user to a POS.** Go to Point of Sale > Configuration > Point of Sale > Select a POS > Assigned Users

Now  except Admin (with Manager role) can open Session on all POS, only assigned user can open sessions in a given POS.